# `docker context create aci` `--location` argument seems to have no effect

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

When using docker compose to deploy a container group to Azure Container Instances, the `--location` argument specified when creating the docker context for aci, `docker context create aci...`, appears to have no effect.

I'm following [these azure instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) for using docker compose with azure container instances
and [this docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#create-an-aci-context) showing the additional arguments for the `docker context create` command

## Steps to re-produce

### Pre-requisites:

Azure CLI

```
λ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.22.1",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.22.1",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

Docker

```
λ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305
```

Docker Compose

```
λ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

### Steps:

1. Log into azure via the cli `az login`
2. Authenticate docker with azure `docker login azure`
3. Create an azure resource group in a specific location `az group create -l uksouth -n test-aci-ctx-group`
4. Create a docker context specifying a location different to the resource group location `docker context create aci aci-context-eastus --resource-group test-aci-ctx-group --location eastus`
5. Display the information about the new context. `docker context inspect aci-context-eastus`
6. **Expected result:** a context bound to the location specified as `--location` for the `docker context create` command, i.e.,  eastus
7. **Actual result:** a context bound to the same location as the azure resource group, i.e., uksouth

```
λ docker context inspect aci-context-eastus
[
    {
        "Name": "aci-context-eastus",
        "Metadata": {
            "Description": "test-aci-ctx-group@uksouth",
            "Type": "aci"
        },
        "Endpoints": {
            "aci": {
                "Location": "uksouth",
                "ResourceGroup": "test-aci-ctx-group",
                "SubscriptionID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "docker": {
                "SkipTLSVerify": false
            }
        },
        "TLSMaterial": {},
        "Storage": {
            "MetadataPath": "xxxx",
            "TLSPath": "xxxx"
        }
    }
]
```

The ultimate manifestation of this issue is that I am unable to create a container group in azure because I'm working in the context of a resource group which I cannot change, but the resource group is in a location that does not support Azure Container Instances.
When I try and issue the `docker-compose up` command in the aci context that I *thought* I created in a location that *supports* azure container instances, I get a location not supported error, listing the location of the resource group and not the location I specified for the docker aci context.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `--location` parameter?

I know you *can* mix and match locations between a container instance and a resource group because I am able to create a container instance via azure cli with a location different to that of the resource group that it is linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the steps. The parameter needs to be used like this:

```
docker context create aci --location "eastus"
```

So you don't need to create the resource group first. When you do it, then the group is already created with a certain location and you can't change it with the docker-compose command.

You have two choices. One is that create the resource group with the location you want, for example, location "eastus". Or create the resource group with the parameter `--location "eastus"` without a name.

Comment: @M Actually, it's not really correct. The resources use the same location as the resource group because the command does not support the options to set the location for the container instance. That's the real reason. So currently, it acts as what I said.  Besides, if it solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Ok, so the `--location` and `--resource-group` are "mutually exclusive" with the resource group and, ultimately _its_ location taking precedence. This does prevent the valid use case of having resources in a resource group with a location different to that of the resource group.

Comment: "...the command does not support the options to set the location for the container instance..." Seems like a bug in the implementation as it's not in line with the underlying azure infrastructure which does allow mixing locations. Doesn't really solve my problem but it does answer my question.

Comment: @Morné Of course, not. You can only create the resource group in your expected location, then the container instance will be created in that location. That's it.